# Inserting record to shared data extension using AMPScript

Tags: ampscript, dataextensions

I am trying to insert new record from form handler page to the shared data extension using AMPScript. But I am getting some access issue while inserting new record.

```
Issue:
ExactTarget.OMM.DataExtensionAccessException: Access to a Data Extension was denied.
Error Code: OMM_DE_ACCESS_DENIED

Code used on form handler page:
InsertData("ENT.DENAME", "FieldName1", @value1, "FieldName2", @value2)
```

Comment: Can you acsess the DE from the UI?

Comment: Yes I can access it from dashboard

Comment: Is that DE shared with the child BU. Check the permissions of the DE or shared folder